# how to change data-frame header based on particular value?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose we have the following csv file like

```
fname,age,class,dob
```

Second csv file name like

```
f_name,user_age,class,DataofBith
```

I am trying to make it common header for all csv file that return same Dataframe of header like in standard manner like

```
first_name,age,class,dob
```

```
val df2 = df.withColumnRenamed("DateOfBirth","DateOfBirth").withColumnRenamed("fname","name")
df2.printSchema()
```

But that way is not generic. Can we do this in a dynamic manner for all CSV as per standard conversion like of DataFrame of CSV in `fname,f_name` it should be converted to the name ?

Comment: are these csv files have same data structure but header with different formatted names and you want created dataframe from each file have same header?

Comment: Yes data structure is same but may be position of columns can be changed.

Comment: The csv may come in any format of header . I need to convert header as per the standard code so that my spark sql query did not need to change.

Comment: Hi @jackson did any of the next answers work for you?

Comment: there was a best answer which is deleted from that post i am searching that one

Comment: one of user posted the answer using fold method . i don't know why he has deleted his answer

Comment: Because is not performant probably @jackson. Using foldLeft in combination with withColumn will hurt performance. Check this for more details https://medium.com/@zcking/tips-for-apache-spark-after-two-years-of-spark-development-dfb566932448. In most of cases a simple select will perform better than a sequence of withColumn calls

Comment: I found some more info about the reasons that foldLeft affects performance @jacksonsmith. Please check [this](https://lansalo.com/2018/05/13/spark-how-to-add-multiple-columns-in-dataframes-and-how-not-to/) and [this](https://medium.com/@manuzhang/the-hidden-cost-of-spark-withcolumn-8ffea517c015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use List of schema then Iterate on top of schema like below -

```
Approach :1
val df= Seq((1,"goutam","kumar"),(2,"xyz","kumar")).toDF("id","fname","lname")
val schema=Seq("id"->"sid","fname"->"sfname","lname"->"slname")
val mapedSchema = schema.map(x=>df(x._1).as(x._2))
df.select(mapedSchema :_*)
```

while reading csv give `"option("header", false)"` then you can get read of mapping of old schema with new schema.

```
Approach :2
val schema=Seq("sid","sfname","slname")
val mapedSchema=data.columns.zip(schema)
val mapedSchemaWithDF = mapedSchema.map(x=>df(x._1).as(x._2))
df.select(mapedSchemaWithDF:_*)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `withColumnRenamed` works also if the column is not present in the dataframe. Hence you can go ahead and read all dataframes and apply the same renaming logic everywhere and union them all later.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def renaming(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
   df.withColumnRenamed("dob", "DateOfBirth")
     .withColumnRenamed("fname", "name")
     .withColumnRenamed("f_name", "name")
     .withColumnRenamed("user_age", "age")
 // append more renaming functions here
}

val df1 = renaming(spark.read.csv("...your path here"))

val df2 = renaming(spark.read.csv("...another path here"))

val result = df1.unionAll(df2)
```

`result` will have the same schema `(DateOfBirth, name, age)` in this case.

Edit:

Following your input, if I understand correctly what you have to do, what about this?

```
val df1 = spark.read.csv("...your path here").toDF("name", "age", "class", "born_date")

val df2 = spark.read.csv("...another path here").toDF("name", "age", "class", "born_date")
```

Comment: This would not work. Because the column name is passed statically. It should be dynamic.

Comment: Also i did not need to merge csv. The csv may come in any format of header . I need to convert header as per the standard code so that my spark sql query did not need to change.

Comment: check my edited reply. I am not sure I understand what you need exacly though.

Comment: Can i pass dynamically header with replace header ?

Comment: can i pass  "// append more renaming functions here " dynamically where first_value comes from the header of csv and second value come from list of static define conversion (standard conversion)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `select` in combination with Scala `Map`. Is easier to handle the column transformations via a dictionary (Map) is which key will be the **old name** and value the **new name**.

Lets create first the two datasets as you described them:

```scala
val df1 = Seq(
  ("toto", 23, "g", "2010-06-09"),
  ("bla", 35, "s", "1990-10-01"),
  ("pino", 12, "a", "1995-10-05")
).toDF("fname", "age", "class", "dob")

val df2 = Seq(
  ("toto", 23, "g", "2010-06-09"),
  ("bla", 35, "s", "1990-10-01"),
  ("pino", 12, "a", "1995-10-05")
).toDF("f_name", "user_age", "class", "DataofBith")
```

Next we have created a Scala function named `transform` which accept two arguments, the target `df` and `mapping` which contains the transformations details:

```scala
val mapping = Map(
  "fname" -> "first_name",
  "f_name" -> "first_name",
  "user_age" -> "age",
  "DataofBith" -> "dob"
)

def transform(df: DataFrame, mapping: Map[String, String]) : DataFrame = {
  val keys = mapping.keySet
  val cols = df.columns.map{c => 
    if(keys.contains(c))
      df(c).as(mapping(c))
    else
      df(c)
  }

  df.select(cols:_*)
}
```

The function goes through the given columns checking first whether the current column exists in `mapping`. If so, it renames using the corresponding value from the dictionary otherwise the column remains untouched. Note that this will just rename the column (via alias) hence we don't expect to affect performance.

Finally, some examples:

```scala
val newDF1 = transform(df1, mapping)
newDF1.show

// +----------+---+-----+----------+
// |first_name|age|class|       dob|
// +----------+---+-----+----------+
// |      toto| 23|    g|2010-06-09|
// |       bla| 35|    s|1990-10-01|
// |      pino| 12|    a|1995-10-05|
// +----------+---+-----+----------+


val newDF2 = transform(df2, mapping)
newDF2.show

// +----------+---+-----+----------+
// |first_name|age|class|       dob|
// +----------+---+-----+----------+
// |      toto| 23|    g|2010-06-09|
// |       bla| 35|    s|1990-10-01|
// |      pino| 12|    a|1995-10-05|
// +----------+---+-----+----------+
```